# How to insert into mysql table some amount of rows with single sql request

Tags: mysql

I met a some situation, when I need insert some rows in mysql table with single sql request. With php it's simple, but I need to do this with only sql request. Is there something like "for" in mysql?

Comment: In MySQL 8.0, yes. Otherwise no. But ordinarily you don't need anything like that to insert multiple rows

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks. And how this "for" look like. For example if I want to insert 100 rows with same values?

Comment: I reject the premise of the question, because I cannot think of any reason why you'd want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this may be it's helpful for you.

```
drop procedure if exists load_foo_test_data;

delimiter #
create procedure load_foo_test_data()
begin

declare v_max int unsigned default 1000;
declare v_counter int unsigned default 0;

    truncate table foo;
    start transaction;
    while v_counter < v_max do
        insert into foo (val) values ( floor(0 + (rand() * 65535)) );
        set v_counter=v_counter+1;
    end while;
    commit;
end #
delimiter ;

call load_foo_test_data();

select * from foo order by id;
```